# Wi-fi connection spotty in ubuntu 20.04.1 (kernel version 5.15.0.43),

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, realtek

I've recently upgraded to 5.15.0.43, and I'm having trouble with a spotty Wi-fi connection using a Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter.

When I'm connected with Wi-fi, the following occurs when I `ping google.com`:

```
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=631 ttl=117 time=494 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=632 ttl=117 time=1022 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=633 ttl=117 time=846 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=635 ttl=117 time=383 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=636 ttl=117 time=1017 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=637 ttl=117 time=16.5 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=638 ttl=117 time=179 ms
```

However, when testing with a wired connection (02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)):

```
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=686 ttl=117 time=10.1 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=687 ttl=117 time=9.93 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=688 ttl=117 time=9.62 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=689 ttl=117 time=9.91 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=690 ttl=117 time=9.77 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=691 ttl=117 time=9.91 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=692 ttl=117 time=10.2 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=693 ttl=117 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=694 ttl=117 time=10.00 ms
```

I've had this issue before when upgrading the kernel version (and I can't revert back to a version that works on boot as I'm three minor versions on from that)

Are there any suggestions as to what I can do to improve the wi-fi with this adapter? It is causing issues when syncing large files via Dropbox, which I don't get when wired.

The drivers I have been using, here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 have not been updated since 2020.

The result of `lpsci -knn | grep Net -A3` is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek 
Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8723de
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8723de
```

NB: I'm currently not at my home network, which is why I can try a wired connection to show such a difference.

EDIT: It's improved a bit, but I'm still dropping packets which doesn't happen with wired:

```
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=176 ttl=117 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=177 ttl=117 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=179 ttl=117 time=1027 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=180 ttl=117 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=183 ttl=117 time=1136 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s27-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.14): icmp_seq=184 ttl=117 time=112 ms
```

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 used the 5.4 kernel only; you'll find you're using 20.04.4 currently with many of the 20.04.5 upgrades already installed (5.15 kernel is part of the 20.04.5 upgrade where using HWE kernel stack). The 20.04.1 you read maybe your installation media or something else, but not likely what you're running (*depending on where you got that detail from*).  You may find switching to GA kernel stack helpful, ie. return to 5.4, which is supported the life of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I'm confused as uname -a returns ````Linux <name> 5.15.0.43-generic #46-20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 14 15:20;17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```` but logging in via ssh reports ````Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15-0-43-generic x86_64)````, two different versions of Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I've followed the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403073/how-to-go-back-from-hwe-5-13-to-ga-5-4-kernel-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts to go back to GA 5.4.0.122 so let's see if that makes a difference