# How to turn on Kernel livepatch

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

I can't turn on the kernel livepatch option, despite trying many times. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's right there in your image, the `NOTICES`: "*The current kernel (5.19.0-43-generic, amd64) is not supported by livepatch*". And then, anticipating your next question, an URL showing you the list of supported kernels.

Comment: @user535733 thanks. But, it is bad? Should I just wait a few updates and then, all back to normal? I might have been using Ubuntu for long, but I don't know everything. Thanks again.

Comment: @user535733 I am a regular user. Most of what I do is libreoffice, and web browing. But I like to work with a stable and secure operating system, which is why I use Ubuntu and not mac, or Windows. I don't do anything fancy with my laptop, but I want it to be right and reliable.

Comment: @user535733 I have never changed the kernel on my own, at least intentionally, but I am confortable on the terminal if that is what I should do.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and then directly paste it in the question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: It seems like your question might be more along the lines of "*How to I switch to a Livepatch-supported kernel?*", since you already know how to turn it on.

Comment: You might want to see https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels as there it explains that the HWE support for Livepatch will start with Kernel 6.2.  Then the support for the HWE with 22.04 will come in July 2023, I am assuming that means that the 6.2 HWE Kernel will be available with the 22.04.3 LTS release.  If you are anything like me and hate to reboot your system all that often, Livepatch is great for helping to reduce system downtime like on my video server.

Comment: @Terrance that is the response that I was looking for, and yes, I don't like rebooting my system if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Livepatch is turned on

Note the following line in the second screenshot in the question:

```
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
```

Also note the following lines in the third screenshot:

```
NOTICES
The current kernel (5.19.0-43-generic, amd64) is not supported by livepatch.
Supported kernels are listed here: https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels
Either switch to a supported kernel or `pro disable livepatch` to dismiss this warning.
```

These lines indicate Livepatch is enabled but is not available for the installed kernels.

The rest of the answer tries to clarify some of the confusion.

## You don't need livepatch

### What is a kernel? How is it updated?

A kernel is the most fundamental part of an operating system like Ubuntu. It starts up very early when the computer starts and it controls everything.

From time to time the kernel is updated with security fixes. This is part of normal software updates. You can setup security updates to update automatically using the Softwares & Updates app. Or you can manually update your Ubuntu using **Software Updater** app. You may also use the following commands to keep the computer updated:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Note, you will need both the commands in that order.

When normal software such as Libreoffice or Firefox is updated Ubuntu does not need to be rebooted to use that software. You can close LibreOffice and start it again and the updated version will start.

This does not normally work for kernel updates. When you use the app **Software Updater** and the kernel is updated you will see a notice that says the computer must be restarted for the kernel update to take effect.

In summary:

1. **Keep your computer updated and kernels will be updated as and when needed.**
2. **Restart your computer when prompted to make sure you are using the most recent kernel.**

### What is kernel livepatch?

Kernel livepach is a mechanism that allows kernels to be updated without restarting the computer. This is like changing a tire of a car while driving it. This is needed in computers used in critical situations. For example, if the computer controls a nuclear power plant, rebooting the computer may not be always possible. My guess is your computer does not control something as critical and you should be able to reboot your computer as and when needed. Thus, you don't need livepatch.

### But what if you *really really* need livepach?

Livepatch is not yet available for Ubuntu LTS HWE kernels. [The list of the kernels that are supported by livepatch is availalbe here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels).

You have two options:

**First,** use the non-HWE LTS kernel. For Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it is the kernel was released with, version 5.15. Since you are already using kernel 5.19 the current HWE kernel, I won't recommend that.

See [How to go back from HWE (5.13) to GA (5.4) kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403073/how-to-go-back-from-hwe-5-13-to-ga-5-4-kernel-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1403081#1403081) for how to go back from HWE to original kernel. The process is similar for Ubuntu 22.04, but it may not work with most recent hardware that needs the newer kernel.

**Second,** wait a few months when the Ubuntu 22.04.3 comes out. That will come with a newer version of the kernel and it will support livepatch in HWE LTE kernels.

See this question and answer for more: [Livepatch -- plans to support official HWE kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395799/livepatch-plans-to-support-official-hwe-kernels)

See this answer for the differences between updating Ubuntu and Windows work: [Does Ubuntu force updates like Windows or I can choose if I want to update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414220/does-ubuntu-force-updates-like-windows-or-i-can-choose-if-i-want-to-update/1414243#1414243)

Hope this helps

Comment: Helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: dude, people like you and answers like this kind of make one feel like even when we don't know each other there's a chance for humanity, build community and we might be ok, after all. Thank you!