# I need downgrade the kernel

Tags: kernel, 22.04, downgrade

I am currently using Ubuntu version 22.04.03LTS, and the kernel is 6.2.0-32-generic.
I need to downgrade to version 5.15.0-41-generic but I can't get it to work.
Can you help me to solve the problem?

Regards, Hector.

Comment: Did you try following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  where the "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*" part of the instructions tells you what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go back from HWE (5.13) to GA (5.4) kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403073/how-to-go-back-from-hwe-5-13-to-ga-5-4-kernel-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)   FYI:  The warning about the instructions relating only to 20.04 is somewhat outdated; it applied to 20.04 & later LTS releases (*alas none existed when the answer was written*)

Comment: This maybe a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to downgrade the kernel?