# How to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 GA

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

### Background

My Ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkEdge SE50 boots into CLI instead of GUI after running updates and removing Python 3.8 (the system Python is 3.10). Now I don't know if either of these two or something else I did is the cause for this problem and I don't even care to find out anymore. I'd rather just do a fresh install because the system is already a mess and I'm busy developing an automated process for setting up the software that I need on that kind of machine anyways.

Due to an obscure hardware/driver compatibility issue, I can't use the HWE stack and need to be on GA with the 5.4 kernel. To be specific, the GA version is required by a proprietary CAN-bus interface (from SUNIX) on that machine.

I remember the last time I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on that machine from an image, it was a lot of work to revert to the 5.4 kernel and deactivate the HWE updates. Hence, I'm looking for an image that I can use to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 GA out of the box. I couldn't find such an image.

### Question

I'm just looking for a simple way to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 GA. The fewer steps, the better.

Comment: I'm aware of [this question about reverting from HWE to GA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403073/how-to-go-back-from-hwe-5-13-to-ga-5-4-kernel-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts) but the given answer appears complicated.

Comment: The answer you don't like ("*appears complicated*") is about as simple as it gets for an already-installed system. You are asking how to do a lung transplant: It's going to be complex. Much of it is testing to ensure that you did it right. It's a good, sensible, safe answer; don't be so fast to reject it.

Comment: All 20.04 Desktop images use the HWE (not GA) kernel metapackage.

Comment: It's still not a full answer though. What image do I have to start with to minimize the number of necessary steps? Like I think if I start with downloading 20.04.1 that should still have kernel 5.4, so I wouldn't have to downgrade and only do the rest of the steps?

Comment: To be clear, I want to format the drives and start from scratch. I don't care about the already-installed system. I've backed up the data.

Comment: The steps do not change if you start with an earlier release. That earlier image is still using HWE metapackages that you must swap for GA metapackages. The volume of packages apt must uninstall/install during some steps is greatly reduced if you use an earlier release (time savings)...but that's entirely automatic. It changes the *complexity* needle not a bit.

Comment: Is there any reason this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate? "That answer's too hard" is not a reason.

Comment: If y'all are sufficiently confident that there is no GA image, closure could be warranted. It all comes down to whether you think reverting from HWE to GA is essentially the same as installing a GA system, or not.

Comment: Your details to me are confusing, as the Desktop requires the *default* version of Python3, which you appear to have changed; you've *corrupted* or *destroyed* many parts of a desktop system thus will be limited to terminal interface (due to python3 default change). All Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 & later media uses HWE; only the Ubuntu *flavors* offer GA or HWE media (selected by the point release), however LTS releases prior to 20.04 of Ubuntu Desktop used the same standard as *flavors* still do as is documented, but you want a non-standard 20.04? using an python3 for a later release??

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack    Only [Ubuntu  Desktop *flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) continue to follow the standard that was used by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & earlier & offer both GA or HWE kernel stacks on install media.  Do note however, that `python3` and other required *infrastructure* packages are **identical** between Ubuntu *flavors* and the main Ubuntu Desktop (you can confirm via *seed* file exploration if you wish (ie. formula of ISO build), or manifests showing versions put on ISO itself after build)

Comment: @guiverc I'm really confused about the Python situation too. I was under the impression that the system Python was Python 3.10. At least that's what opened when calling `python` and it has been like this for a long time. In any case, after I thought I had uninstalled Python 3.8 and rebooting, Python 3.8 was there. In any case, it's time for a fresh install, I bet it's more expensive to repair the system than to start over.

Comment: Python 3.10 is *default* for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but you're not using 22.04 according to your question (3.10 didn't exist in 2020-April when 20.04 was released!).   You do realize you can non-destructively re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system ....   I wrote about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) which applies to *flavors* too

Comment: There's nothing on the system worth saving. I also need to document how to make that install (including specific software) anyways. That's why I'd like a fresh install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go back from HWE (5.13) to GA (5.4) kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403073/how-to-go-back-from-hwe-5-13-to-ga-5-4-kernel-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

Comment: The suggestion by @guiverc to install an Ubuntu flavor could be a suitable answer to my question. However, I just tried to track down Lubuntu 20.04 GA and didn't recognize it among the [releases](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/). I'm also not sure on all the other implications of using a flavor (hardware compatibility, updates, etc.).

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS along with all 20.04 *flavors* is EOL (https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/) as *flavors* only have 3 years of supported life; 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc. The Lubuntu 20.04 LTS & Lubuntu 20.0.4.1 LTS media (*along with all flavors!*) install & use the GA kernel stack; however 20.04.2 & later media all use the HWE kernel stack like Ubuntu Desktop. All Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS media use the GA kernel stack don't forge (Ubuntu Desktop from 20.04 all use HWE by default). *flavor* media isn't kept as long